# Firestore admin query fails on larger collections

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I built an admin dashboard on the client where I call a function in the cloud to get the docs for a selected collection. The query in the function looks like that:

```
  adminDb
    .collection(selectedCollection)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      if (snapshot.size === 0) throw new functions.https.HttpsError('not-found', 'No entries found')

      return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        return {
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }
      })
    })
```

In my case, this works for a collection with roughly 500 entries although it already takes quite a while:

```
callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution started

callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution took 1298 ms, finished with status code: 204

callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution started

callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution took 4528 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

Querying a collection with 1'800 entries, I get the following error:

```
callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution started

callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution took 14 ms, finished with status code: 204

callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution started

callableAdminGetDocs
Function execution took 19258 ms, finished with status: 'response error'
```

while on client side I receive these logs:

```
POST https://us-central1-[].cloudfunctions.net/callableAdminGetDocs 502
[]:1 Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-[].cloudfunctions.net/callableAdminGetDocs' from origin 'https://[].com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

What's the issue here? Is it a general restriction using these kind of admin queries of being super inefficient and therefore fail for "larger" collections?

Comment: Consider using pagination instead of loading everything into memory.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: @DougStevenson I've tried but I have not figured out yet how I could `orderBy` something generic like docId which is needed - as far as I understood - to use `limit()` and `startAt()` on the query. Does this also mean that functions are very limited in these matters?

Comment: @DougStevenson Any further hints on how to overcome the points mentioned?